# "На уровне, достаточном для..." - нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

Инструменты знаю на уровне достаточном для настройки сервера.

Нужно ли обрамлять запятыми "достаточном для настройки сервера"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно, нужно. Ведь это распространённое определение, стоящее после определяемого существительного. Такое определение, которое надо обрамлять запятыми, называется обособленным.

А вот если бы оно стояло перед определяемым существительным, оно бы не обособлялось.  Есть некоторые исключения, но обычно после существительного обособляется, перед ним не обособляется. Подробнее: http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/1946d260-e1a1-4308-8126-72b39aaea09a/punc18.htm

Answer (score 3):

К своему удивлению я обнаружил, что де-факто перед "достаточном для" действительно ставят запятую. Обоснованием тому служит тот факт, что определительные обороты, стоящие после существительного должны обособляться. А именно, согласно [общепринятым правилам](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/262-obosoblennyeopredeleniyaiprilogeniya.html):

> Как правило, обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) согласованные распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или
>   прилагательным с зависимыми от них словами и стоящие после
>   определяемого слова.

Лично для меня это, повторюсь, большой сюрприз. В то время, как я согласен с обособлением в абсолютно всех примерах, приведённых по ссылке, и вместе с тем интуитивно не понимаю, почему "достаточном" тоже должно обособляться. Видимо, этот подпадает под пункт определения, имеющего уточняющее значение.

Замечу, что в интернете - даже в официальных документах, можно встретить "на уровне, достаточном, для" - вот вторая запятая точно не нужна и я бы назвал это случаем пунктуационной гиперкоррекции.

Comment: Логика, по-моему, вот какая: если написать без запятой "знаю на уровне достаточном для настройки сервера", то не сразу понятно, к чему это "для настройки сервера" относится: к слову "знаю" или к слову "достаточном".  Без запятых такие предложения были бы тяжелее для понимания.  Если "знаю на достаточном для настройки сервера уровне", то сразу очевидно, что "для настройки сервера" относится к слову "достаточном"